# Are request's callback always called?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request, npm

I work with the `npm` module `request`, but a lot of time some requests are never called back, which causes many problems.

So I am wondering, is request supposed to always callback? Like, if my request timeout, does it callback with an error, or does it just ignore my callback?

If it ignores it, how could I be 100% sure to have my function called and able to know that the request didn't work in any case?

Comment: [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) doesn't ignore callbacks, if it's used properly. Just be sure to have a listener for `error` event (timeout is an error).
If you want a more specific answer, post some code :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, callback function is always executed.

```
var opt = {
    url: 'http://stackoverflow.com',
    timeout: 1 // one milisecond, my ping is 100 ms
};

request.get(opt, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.stack);
    } else {
        console.log(body);
    }
});
```

Output:

```
Error: ETIMEDOUT
    at null._onTimeout (C:\node\node_modules\request\request.js:677:15)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

You can look into request code how request emit this error:

https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/request.js#L750